# Solve the ODE $y'' + y ' = y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the ODE $$ y''+ y' = y^2$$
I tried to solve, but I don't know any algorithm except for numerical methods.

Comment: Also check, if you wrote down the equation correctly. If this is an exercise it might be that something went wrong in typesetting the equation.

Answer (score 7):

First, rewrite the ODE as $y''=-y'+y^2=F(y,y')$.

This type of ODE can be reduced to a first order ODE by the following trick. Define $y'(x)=v(y(x)).$ Differentiation of this expression (using the chain rule) with respect to $x$ results in:

$$y''(x)=\dfrac{dv}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{dy}y'(x)=\dfrac{dv}{dy}v(y)=\dfrac{dv}{dy}v.$$

Again, using the right-hand side of the ODE we obtain:

$$\dfrac{dv}{dy}v=-(y')+y^2=-(v)+y^2 \implies v+v\dfrac{dv}{dy}=y^2.$$

The resulting ODE is an [Abel Differential equation of the second kind](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0126.pdf). I don't think that there is a closed form solution as Maple couldn't solve it. I also tried to determine the Lie Symmetries of this ODE with the symgen() function that is available in the Maple package DETools which only gave a translational symmetry. You could try other packages for Maple / Mathematica / Mupad / Sympy. There is also a paper by [Ali Rostami (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.05929) that deals with these type of ODEs.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:)** Let $y'=u$ and $y''=uu'$ now solve $uu'+u=y^2$.

Comment: yes. here $y$ is independent variable.

Comment: $$y''=\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=u'u$$